# I have three font type -Gotham-bold, Gotham-medium, Gotham-thin, so do I need to use three times @font-face?

Tags: css, font-face

Actually I have three files in the fonts folder. These are `Gotham-Bold.ttf`, `Gotham-Medium.ttf`, `Gotham-Thin.ttf`..... So do I need to use the `@font-face` three times for those three types. Please anybody help me.

I have currently used the code like the following:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham';
    src: url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     }

     @font-face {
      font-family: 'Gotham';
      src: url("/fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot");
     }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Gotham';
      src: url("/fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff") format("woff");
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is correct, you'll need an `@font-face` for each weight of the font you want to use.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Bold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
   font-weight: 700;
   font-style: normal;
 }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: normal;
 }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Thin.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Thin.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Thin.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('fonts/Gotham-Thin.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
   font-weight: 300;
   font-style: normal;
 }
```

Then you can use your fonts as so:

```
body {
   font-family: 'Gotham';
}

// For normal
.normal {
  font-weight: 400;
}

// For bold
.bold,
strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

// For thin
.light {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to declare each font-type as a separate `@fontface`. Each would be a different font-family in that case.

Like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamThin';
  /* links to all gotham thin files, font-weight/style declaration */
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamMedium';
  /* links to all gotham medium files, font-weight/style declaration */
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamBold';
  /* links to all gotham bold files, font-weight/style declaration */
}
```

Only include the fonts you are using, though.. if you don't use Gotham Thin anywhere on the page, don't include it (for speed).

Comment: I think using the font-weight like the previous comment and using it both are same. Right ? Thank you.