# font face not working if font format is specified

Tags: css, node.js, font-face, webfonts

I'm using node to make a server on localhost. 
I can't load font via css fontface when I access page via the localhost. 
on the same folder I have a test.html page that work fine when access directly. (not via local host.) So I guess my problem come from the serve.js file. 
My fonts are in public/font. my index.html in public too, and my css are in public/css. 
here it is :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1881; 

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');
    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './public/index.html';
    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
        case '.png':
            contentType = 'image/png';
            break;      
        case '.jpg':
            contentType = 'image/jpg';
            break;
        case '.wav':
            contentType = 'audio/wav';
            break;
        case '.woff2':
            contentType = 'application/font-woff2';
            break;
        case '.woff':
            contentType = 'application/font-woff';
            break;
    }
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}).listen(port);
console.log("Server Running on "+port+".\nLaunch http://localhost:"+port);
```

ok, so the problem comme from not from node, but from stylus ? if i'm doing this :

```
@font-face
    font-family Knockout
    src url(../font/Knockout-HTF28-JuniorFeatherwt.woff2),url(../font/Knockout-HTF28-JuniorFeatherwt.woff)
```

It works, if I'm doing this :

```
@font-face
    font-family Knockout
    src url(../font/Knockout-HTF28-JuniorFeatherwt.woff2)  format(woff2),url(../font/Knockout-HTF28-JuniorFeatherwt.woff)  format(woff)
```

It doesn't work...
Any idea ?

Comment: As I tried to access your font file, there occurs a 403 Error "AccessDenied"

Comment: ok, I should have said I was working with nodejs, using http.createServer. I think the problem come from here, since a test.html page in the same folder work fine when it's not accessed via localhost. I don't know why the server block the font.

Answer (score 1):

Download the webfonts and use them as such:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
    }
```

You can put the whole path in the URL because sometimes on localhost they only work like that.

Comment: I tried, but i still have the same problem. Shouldn't I have a 404 in console if it fail to load the font ?

Answer (score 1):

First Download the font into your local pc

*I will use `Open Sans font` just for demo*

**Note**: Please check your font file is in **fonts** folder, and your css file is out of the **fonts** folder?

Let me know further clarification

Font face is should be like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
       url('../fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.svg#OpenSans') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

If this trick is can't work then use below trick, B'coz It's all depends your folder structure.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
       url('fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.svg#OpenSans') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: I have the current folder structure : index.html in the same folder as css folder (css/style.css), and font folder (font/Gotham-Black.woff). So it should work with ../font/Gotham-Black.woff, no ?

Comment: Then you should be try into your font face like-url(./font/Gotham-Black.woff) And (/font/Gotham-Black.woff)
And please check your .ttf file. This file is already installed or not if not then please install.

For more detail you can visit this link:-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836956/i-have-three-font-type-gotham-bold-gotham-medium-gotham-thin-so-do-i-need-to

Comment: Hi @jaydeep patel, thanks, but I found the problem, it was a stylus problem, it's solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for any one stubling on this here is the answer, stylus was to blame.

This is working :

```
src url(../font/Knockout-HTF28-JuniorFeatherwt.woff2)  format("woff2"),url(../font/Knockout-HTF28-JuniorFeatherwt.woff)  format("woff")
```

Thanks to this :
https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2329